# Unable to completely force browsers to cache resources - gsCacheBuster comes in

Tags: url, caching, http-headers, browser-cache

Proper caching is very important for us as we aim to reduce traffic.
I've configured communication for resources as so:

This is the request URL:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/resources/product/assets/swf/modules/loader.swf?ver=1
```

These are the response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:14622
Content-Type:application/x-shockwave-flash
Date:Tue, 22 May 2012 09:16:41 GMT
ETag:"7804f-391e-4c08e046d3ec0"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=96
Last-Modified:Mon, 21 May 2012 16:01:39 GMT
P3P:CP="HONK"
Server:Apache
```

I need to force the browsers to cache the resources I pass back. As far as I know these headers should be sufficient to cache resources. But...

***For some resources a strange thing, called gsCacheBuster, comes in:***

Request URL:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/resources/product/assets/images/image1.png
?gsCacheBusterID=1337684498911&purpose=audit&ver=1
```

Which changes the URL and the resource is therefore not cached.

As you can see we've implemented functionality in the client (which is Flash in the case) to pass a ***ver*** parameter along the request to make sure the current version is being downloaded. This way we aim to maintain versioning of resources and force browsers to cache resources with the same version.

I have no idea why this cacheBuster appears and couldn't find any info. It happens in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it is a LoaderMax property, since we use the Greensock library in our Flash client. It can be disabled with setting the setter noCache to false and also remove audits.